# Efficient Database Queries ( PHP + PDO SQL)

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

At the moment I have a database structure like so:

```
| id | name            | parent_id
| 1  | Human Resources | 0
| 2  | Marketing       | 0
| 3  | Operations      | 0
| 4  | Design          | 0
| 5  | Marketing Design| 4
| 6  | Graphic Design  | 4
| 7  | Print Design    | 4
| 8  | Human Personal  | 1
| 9  | Food Ops        | 3
```

As you can see these are the departments within the business and also sub departments.

A sub-departments **parent_id** is the id of the **department**

do, for example:

> id: 4,  name: Design, parent_id: 0
>
> id: 7, Print Design,  parent_id: 4
>
> Print Design is a sub department of design

I have called everything from the database in one query and now I need them in this structure:

```
$depts = array(
   "Human Resources" => array("Human Personal"),
   "Marketing" => array(),
   "Operations" => array("Food Ops"),
   "Design" => array("Marketing Design", "Graphic Design", "Print Design"),
   ...
);
```

so far I have:

```
 foreach ($results as $result) {

    if ($result['parent_id'] == 0) {
        $parentCategories_arr[array($result['id'] => $result['name'])];
    } else {
        $returnedResults_arr[$result['parent_id']] = array($result['name']);
    }
}
```

However I completely think that I have missed the point. so my question:

How do I loop through all the contents of that results and add the parent categories into an array with their sub categories as an array?

Comment: you can use method which take parent id and get sub categories you can do this recursive

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is an easier way, but it works : (hate to say that sentence) - try to make it better maybe

```
$mFinalArray = fixMyArray($results);

print_r($mFinalArray);

function fixMyArray($results){

    // Create categories - parent_id == 0
    foreach($results as $index => $result)                           // $index = 0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9
        if($result['parent_id'] == 0)                                // $result['parent_id'] = current item parent_id
            $mCategories[$result['name']] = $result['id'];           // $mCategories['Human Resources'] = 1|2|3|4

    // Insert each data to the right parent
    foreach($results as $index => $result)                           // $index = 0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8
        if($result['parent_id'] != 0)
            foreach($mCategories as $subindex => $category)          // $subindex = Human Resources | Marketing | Operations | Design
                if($result['parent_id'] == $category)                // $category = 0|1|2|3|4
                        $mFinalArray[$subindex][] = $result['name']; // ex. $mFinalArray['Human Resources'][] = Human Personal

    return $mFinalArray;    

}
```

*Last line has an extra **[ ]** `$mFinalArray[$subindex]`**[ ]**`= $result['name']`  . That means append to array.

Output :

```
Array
(
    [Design] => Array
        (
            [0] => Marketing Design
            [1] => Graphic Design
            [2] => Print Design
        )

    [Human Resources] => Array
        (
            [0] => Human Personal
        )

    [Operations] => Array
        (
            [0] => Food Ops
        )

)
```